# 15>LINK : fatal error LNK1181..\scripts\Release\scripts.lib" cannot be open

Tags: azerothcore

I wanna try to compile a fresh core with some custom modules,
but get always this error 15>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: Eingabedatei "..\scripts\Release\scripts.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden. I Already tried to delete the master and build folder and try it again..same error. Cmake configure works without any problems. what did i wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

During your CMake configuration, did you make sure your scripts were generated? On Ungrouped entries there should be a tick like this:

[image]

Another problem that usually happens when you generate projects on windows are the special characters from paths. If the path where your project is has some sort of non-english characters like "**ç**" then this might be confusing the IDE since he might not be finding the path. Make sure your server is on a folder on root to avoid these situations for example: "C:\azerothcore_server". If this all doesn't solve your issue, show us your CMake configurations.

### **Solved problem**

The problem was that OP had a module that was having issues so his problem was linked from a file that was not compiled successfully making the worlserver application to fail by default.
For future reference, make sure you report the whole stack error so you can trace back what failed.